# warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch ONLY when I include Identical Functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am lost, when I ran my program last night it ran fine. When I added the `power()` function, suddenly lines **which ran fine without adding the new code** now trigger an error message:

> warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch

Why?

I feel I don't have the chops to explain this, so please follow the code below.

**PLEASE RUN THE CODE WITH AND WITHOUT THIS `power()` FUNCTION**. When run with the `power()` function, it makes error C4018 on the `for` loops in the `exam()` function!  When run without the `power()` function, it runs FINE!!

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

///the offending function///
double power(double base, int exponent)
{
    double product;
    //double base; int exponent;
    std::cout << "enter a value for base: " << endl;
    std::cin >> base;
    std::cout << "enter exponenent: " << endl;
    std::cin >> exponent;
    double result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
        //product = base  exponent;
    }
    std::cout << product;
    return product;
}

///after here, things run fine if you X out the aforementioned function! Wow!

void exam()
{
    std::vector<int> scores;
    int F;
    F = 0; //string names;
    std::cout << "enter exam scores int:" << endl;

    //std::vector <string> names;
    while (F != -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a new exame score:" << endl;
        std::cin >> F;
        scores.push_back(F);
    }
    if (F == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "end of score entering" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << scores[i];
    }

    /*
     while (i < scores.size())
     {
     std::cout << scores[i];
     i++;
     }
     */
    std::cout << "yay you made this work!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl;

}

int multiply()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    a = 8;
    b = 4;
    std::cout << a * b << endl;

    std::cout << "f*** yeah" << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}

void test()
{
    std::vector<int> newvector;
    int T;
    std::cout << "enter vector variables: " << endl;
    std::cin >> T;
    newvector.push_back(T);
    while (T != -1)
    {
        std::cout << "enter new vector variables T " << endl;
        std::cin >> T;
        newvector.push_back(T);
        if (T == -1)
        {
            newvector.pop_back();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "end of NewVector data inputs:" << endl;
    for (int W = 0; W < newvector.size(); W++)
    {
        std::cout << newvector[W] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    power(2, 3);
    exam();
    /*int result = multiply();
     std::cout << "endl ;" << endl;
     test();
     system("pause"); */
    multiply();
    string name;
    int a;
    std::cout << "enter a variable for your name: " << endl;
    std::getline(cin, name);
    if (name == "aaron")
    {
        std::cout << " what a dumb name, aAron?" << endl;
    }
    else if (name == "todd")
    {
        std::cout << "what a dottly name, Todd" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "your name = " << name << endl;
    }

    //std::vector <string>

    std::vector<int> asdf;
    std::cout << "enter an int for a" << endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    asdf.push_back(a);
    while (a != -1)
    {
        std::cout << "enter another A: " << endl;
        std::cin >> a;
        asdf.push_back(a);
        if (a == -1)
        {
            asdf.pop_back();
        }
    } //set var; checks if d<size(); if so, JUMP to std::cout<<; when finished with body, find  after size(); == "d++", then refer back to declaration)

    /*/ for(int G = 0; G<asdf.size(); G++)
     {
     std::cout << asdf[G] << endl;
     } */

    for (int i = 0; i < asdf.size(); i++)
    {

        std::cout << asdf[i] << "f*** it works!!!!!! " << endl;
    }

    for (int d = 0; d < asdf.size(); d++)
    { //htt ps://youtu.be/_1AwR-un4Hk?t=155

        std::cout << asdf[d] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << endl;
    std::cout << std::accumulate(asdf.begin(), asdf.end(), 0);
    //std::cout<<

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is a question about the tool (Visual Studio), not the language. Please specify the exact version of Visual Studio and your exact sequence of operations in it. Adding `power` function should not affect the warning.

Comment: There is nothing `power()` does, or can do, that makes the `for` or `while` loops work any differently, with or without a compiler diagnostic. Your loops are comparing `int` to `size_t`, that is always a warning, period. The code may RUN perfectly fine, since you are likely to not add enough entries to the `vector` to exceed what an `int` can represent.

Comment: Also, just FYI, the standard library has its own power functions in `<cmath>`: [`std::pow()`, `std::powf()`, and `std::powl()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow), so you don't need to make your own `power()` function (especially since you are not even using it correctly, anyway).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks, what do you mean by "size_t"? how's that superior to (vector).size, and why is .size even an option if (size_t) is better?

Comment: @Darkhessian02 [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is an **unsigned integer** data type that most standard containers use, and is what `size()` returns (technically, for a `vector`, `vector::size_type` is the actual type used, but that is usually `size_t`).  Comparing a **signed** `int` to an **unsigned** type like `size_t` can cause issues if you are not careful, which is why the compiler usually issues a warning on such comparisons.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, so should I (a newbie) be initializing my for-indices with size_t? ((rather than 
for (int i =0;.....) 

I would try 

for (size_t i=0;....)

thank you sir

Comment: @Darkhessian02 the type of the loop counter should ideally be the same as the value being compared to. So, if you are looping through a container and using its `size()` as the loop condition, you should use the container's `size_type` for the loop counter, eg: `std::vector<int> scores; for (decltype(scores)::size_type i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++)`, `std::vector<int> newvector; for (decltype(newvector)::size_type W = 0; W < newvector.size(); W++)`, etc. Many people fudge this and just use `size_t` directly.

Answer (score 2):

The presence of the `power` function should have no effect on this problem. Possibly you aren't seeing the warnings because without the `power` function the program does not compile.

In

```
for (int W = 0; W < newvector.size(); W++)
```

`newvector.size()` [returns an unsigned integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size). `int W` is a signed integer. You're getting exactly what you asked for.

You can change `int W` to `vector<int>::size_type W` (but the less verbose `size_t W` should also work) to make the error message go away, but this is an error where you would likely have to add more than 2 billion items to the `vector` to see manifest.

Solution:

```
for (vector<int>::size_type W = 0; W < newvector.size(); W++)
```

However this is a good place for [a range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```cpp
for (const auto &val: newvector) 
{ 
    std::cout << val << endl; 
}
```

By letting the compiler figure out all the sizes and types your life is much easier.

This is repeated several times throughout the code.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question in the title: why it happens `ONLY when I include Identical Functions`. Please see (3) in my answer.

Comment: @user4581301 hope this @ summons thee, but for context, I have no idea what "auto &val: " would do, as I am a newcomer to C++. 

what are you saying, that the line "newvector.size()" needs to be declared as an INT?

Thank you!

Comment: *newvector.size()" needs to be declared as an INT?* The opposite. The `size` function does not return an `int`. It's a library function so you don't want to try to change it to an `int` (you need insane amounts of skill to go hacking around in the standard library without breaking things and the C++ Standard--the rule book of C++--says it must return an unsigned integer), so you are better off changing the type of variable `W` is

Comment: *auto &val: would do* Loop through every entry in `newvector` and call the entry `val`. `auto` means infer the type. Whatever is stored in `newvector`, `int`s, decides the type of `val`. `&` is make a reference to the element  in `newvector`. `val` is the name of the variable. All together this makes `val` a reference to an `int` in `newvector`. I use auto because now I can keep using the exact same loop over and over and only have to change the container I want to iterate. the loop can take any data structure that `<<` knows how to print.

Comment: @Darkhessian02 see [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) on cppreference.com (I suggest you become familiar with that site, it has a lot of useful reference material for C++).

Answer (score -1):

Re: `WHEN RUN, It makes error C4018` -

1. YOU made that error (warning, actually), not "it".
2. That warning is reported by compiler, so you haven't run anything yet...
3. Your newly added function uses uninitialized variable `product`; in my version of Visual Studio it is an error.

Comment: Regardless of the down-vote, my (3) points to an error reported by Visual Studio, that likely causes OP to look into his `Output` window an notice the warnings that were always there, even when his program ran (before introducing that error)